# Putting a line into a frame with proper positioning

Tags: header-footer, framed

I wanted to use a header which looks like the image attached below. At first I tried using a `fbox` with a `parbox` but I had issues with the right widths because the text wasn't properly aligned at all. What would be your attempt at mimicking the style of the first three lines in the sample?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `\framebox` and `tabular*`.

The first line is set in a `\textwidth` wide box, to avoid overfilling; the `\framebox` is set wider exactly by the amount of `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` on either side, so the text is typeset exactly on the text width. The inner `\hfill` kills all other stretchabilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

{% the header
\centering\scshape
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \framebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule][s]{%
    Zentrum Matematik\hfill
    Technische Universität München%
  }%
}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
Prof. Dr. Daniel Matthes & WS 2015/16 \\
Dr. Carl-Friedrich Kreiner & Info-Blatt
\end{tabular*}

}

\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries Analysis I
\end{center}

\noindent
Zur Vorlesung \emph{Analysis I} gehören blah blah
Zur Vorlesung \emph{Analysis I} gehören blah blah
Zur Vorlesung \emph{Analysis I} gehören blah blah
Zur Vorlesung \emph{Analysis I} gehören blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is two solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

bla bla

{\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}{Some text at left}&
\multicolumn{1}{p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\raggedleft Some text at right}\\
\hline
Some text at left & Some text at left\\
Some text at left & Some text at left\\
\end{tabular}}


bla bla foo bar


{\noindent
\framebox[\textwidth]{Some text at left \hfill Some text at left}
Some text at left \hfill Some text at left

\noindent
Some text at left \hfill Some text at left}
\end{document}
```